# Swap around key and value (containing a list) within a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a reference dictionary with subjects and page numbers  like so:

```
reference = { 'maths': [3, 24],'physics': [4, 9, 12],'chemistry': [1, 3, 15] }
```

I need help  writing a function that inverts the reference. That is, returns a dictionary with page numbers as keys, each with an associated list of subjects. For example, swap(reference) run on the above example should return

```
{ 1: ['chemistry'], 3: ['maths', 'chemistry'], 4: ['physics'], 
9: ['physics'], 12: ['physics'], 15: ['chemistry'], 24: ['maths'] }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
reference = { 'maths': [3, 24],'physics': [4, 9, 12],'chemistry': [1, 3, 15] }
for a, b in reference.items():   
    for i in b:    
        d[i].append(a)
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{1: ['chemistry'], 3: ['maths', 'chemistry'], 4: ['physics'], 9: ['physics'], 12: ['physics'], 15: ['chemistry'], 24: ['maths']}
```

Without importing from `collections`:

```
d = {}
for a, b in reference.items():
    for i in b:
        if i in d:
           d[i].append(a)
        else:
           d[i] = [a]
```

Output:

```
{1: ['chemistry'], 3: ['maths', 'chemistry'], 4: ['physics'], 9: ['physics'], 12: ['physics'], 15: ['chemistry'], 24: ['maths']}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very cleaver.  Is there an alternative however without the use of any imported libraries

Comment: The above works for the random example I chose, but I now have discovered that if some of the pages are the same, above will unfortunately not work.  For example: reference = {'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1]}     will give {1:['c']} and ignore 'a' and 'b'

Comment: @Pompi That is strange, as when I ran this code on the new `reference` variable that you posted, I got this output: `{1: ['a', 'c', 'b']}`. `a` and `b` are not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```py
reference = {'maths': [3, 24], 'physics': [4, 9, 12], 'chemistry': [1, 3, 15]}
table = []
newReference = {}

for key in reference:
    values = reference[key]
    for value in values:
        table.append((value, key))

for x in table:
    if x[0] in newReference.keys():
        newReference[x[0]] = newReference[x[0]] + [x[1]]
    else:
        newReference[x[0]] = [x[1]]

print(newReference)
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, the above works for the random example I chose, but I now have discovered that if some of the pages are the same, above will unfortunately not work.  For example: reference = {'a': [1], 'b': [1], 'c': [1]}     will give {1:['c']} and ignore 'a' and 'b'

Comment: Hi Pompi, I was wondering if you could check your python installation.
I used your input and get  `{1: ['b', 'c', 'a']}` as expected.